ffmpeg - mpegts Multicast
I'm generating a multicast stream with this command:
ffmpeg -hwaccel_device 1 -format_code Hi50 -re -f decklink -i 'DeckLink Duo (1)' -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v h264_nvenc -profile:v high -b:v 3500k -rc 2 -cbr true -maxrate 3500k -bufsize 7000k -c:a mp2 -b:a 192k -f mpegts "udp://239.1.1.2:5000?ttl=2&pkt_size=1316"

My problem is that if I open this stream on a device with a 100Mb/s connection, it's heavily pixelated. The same stream on a 1Gb/s device displays fine.
I have other multicast streams from our ISP and they display fine regardless of connection speed.
Has someone come across this issue? This seems ffmpeg related.
I tried several settings, bitrates, etc. Also playing on VLC, OBS. Same result.
Version:
ffmpeg version N-111519-gefa6cec759

Thanks in advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
